# How to add a list of objects inside a list in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a view model containing list of sections like below. I need to create a list of ResponseEntryViewModel and add sections and sub sections inside sections and questions inside subsections.

Any suggestions?

```
public class ResponseEntryViewModel
{
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public List<SectionDataModel> Sections{ get; set; }

    public ResponseEntryViewModel()
    {
        Sections = new List<SectionDataModel>();           
    }

    public class SectionDataModel
    {
        public int SectionID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public List<SubSectionModel> SubSections { get; set; }
        public SectionDataModel()
        {
            SubSections = new List<SubSectionModel>();
        }
    }

    public class SubSectionModel
    {
        public int SubSectionID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int SectionId { get; set; }
        public List<QuestionModel> QuestionsList { get; set; }
        public SubSectionModel()
        {

            QuestionsList = new List<QuestionModel>();
        }
    }

    public class QuestionModel
    {
        public int SubSectionID { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you specify your problem a bit more, seems a bit unclear.

Comment: you don't need to add a contructor on the SubSectionModel and ResponseEntryViewModel classes

Comment: You should avoid creating class inside class. And you must be know how to use `new` to create new objects of the class and use `Add` method to add objects to the List. Did you try using them?

Comment: Yes I tried that @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: What happened when you tried? Can you share that code? Are you getting any error? What error?

Comment: try the following link : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/simple-way-of-binding-list-of-objects-to-view-using-mvc/

Comment: When i try to use foreach loop and assign values to object and try to add in the list, last object element is added in the list repeatedly. For eg if there are 4 sections then last one will be added in all 4 records. @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Without looking at the code, we don't know what is wrong and what needs to be corrected. So you need to share your code.

Comment: Thank you ChetanRanpariya and @DipakRathod, it seems In was not creating a new object everytime in the foreach loop because of which it was adding the last element in the entire list. Got it fixed and working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ResponseEntryViewModel
{
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public List<SectionDataModel> Sections { get; set; }

    public ResponseEntryViewModel(SectionDataModel obj)
    {
        Sections = new List<SectionDataModel>();
        Sections.Add(obj);
    }

    public class SectionDataModel
    {
        public int SectionID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public List<SubSectionModel> SubSections { get; set; }
        public SectionDataModel(SubSectionModel obj)
        {
            SubSections = new List<SubSectionModel>();
            SubSections.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    public class SubSectionModel
    {
        public int SubSectionID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int SectionId { get; set; }
        public List<QuestionModel> QuestionsList { get; set; }

        public SubSectionModel(QuestionModel obj)
        {
            QuestionsList = new List<QuestionModel>();
            QuestionsList.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    public class QuestionModel
    {
        public int SubSectionID { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
    }
}
```